# Showing more form inputs on selection

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create a bit of a listing page. So basically they enter the details about a product. A button below says "Add another product".

How would I go about making it so when someone clicks the button, it shows another set of html `<input>`?

Comment: You use DOM manipulation functions like `document.createElement`, `document.appendChild`, etc.

Comment: Adding an element is simple. Getting it in the right context with a label, value, surrounding elements (maybe it's in a new row in a table?) and appropriate properties takes a lot more effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery to append an `input` on click:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <input type="text"/>
</div>
<button>ADD</button>
```

**JS**

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $(".container").append("<input type='text'/>"); 

});
```

[**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8eLhgh5/)

## **OR**

with plain javascript:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <input type="text"/>
</div>
<button onclick="add()">ADD</button>
```

**JS**

```
function add(){
   var newInput = document.createElement("input");
   newInput.type = "text";     
   document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newInput); 
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8eLhgh5/1/)

Comment: Simpler than I thought! Thank you. Makes sense.

Comment: @KriiV no problem. I added a plain javascript solution too. If this answered your question can you please check this off as resolved?